# Special Characters and Converting Problems Using Tabula for PDF to Proper CSV

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The code:

```
#Import the required Module
import tabula
# Read a PDF File
df=tabula.read_pdf("C:/Users/Desktop/abstract/abstract.pdf",encoding='cp1252', pages='all')
#Total page number can change. All pages must be taken. (to be generic)

# convert PDF into CSV
df1=df.to_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/abstract.pdf')
print(df1)
```

Hello friends, I have a monthly account statement in pdf. I want to get the name and period information as text, save the date, info, amount, and gift information as CSV and read it.
I tried something called tabula read but couldn't get a file the way I wanted. In addition, there are special characters in the pdf file. These are also decoded incorrectly (ğ, ü, ç, etc.)

How can I get the format which I want? So mean I can't reach İşlem tarihi,Açıklama,Tutar,Bankomat Para columns in CSV file or Is there any better way to convert pdf to CSV file?
[image]

**original version (2 pages):**

[image]

**original version end of the page:**
[image]

Comment: Did you try this? `tabula.convert_into("C:/Users/Desktop/abstract/abstract.pdf", "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')`

Comment: it produces only this: (just 6 rows, missing columns) and it shows last page's bottom informations.
,*** numaralı karta ait işlemler,
,Bankomat Para Bilgileriniz,
"Devreden(TL)
-8,0300,""Bu Dönem Kazanılan(TL)"
-6,7800","Hesaba Aktarılan(TL)
0,0000","Toplam(TL)
-14,8100"

Comment: @murattaşçı Why was this tagged with PyPDF2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:

```
#libraries
import pandas as pd
import fitz 
import io

def set_texts(pdf_files:list):
    print("starting to text process")
    #This function reads pdf and gets "CRC-32" components as texts
    for pdf_file in pdf_files:
        with fitz.open(pdf_file) as doc:
            text = ""
            for page in doc:
                new_text = page.get_text()
                text += new_text
        
    return text
file_names = [r"C:/Users/Desktop/abstract/Alışveris_Özeti.pdf"]
text = set_texts(file_names)

buffer = io.StringIO(text)
new_text = ""
flag = False
i = 0
for line in buffer.readlines():
   # print(line)  
    if "Bankomat Para Bilgileriniz" in line:
        flag = False
     
    
    elif "Bankomat Para (TL)" in line:
        flag = True
    
 
    elif "Vakıfbank" in line:
        flag = False
    elif flag:
        new_text += line
        
    elif "Sayın" in line :
         name=(line.lstrip("Sayın ")).replace(",","")
         print(name)


buffer = io.StringIO(new_text)
text_list = buffer.readlines()
 

# /n correction
a = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ''), text_list))
# Converting 4 spaces to single space
b = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('    ', ' '), a))

# card vocabulay
c = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('BANKOMAT KART ', 'BANKOMAT KART'), b))

# undesired words
stopwords = ['BANKOMAT KART','İŞLEMİ', 'ALIŞVERİŞ EKSTRESİ', 'Dekont yerine kullanılmaz. Uyuşmazlık halinde Banka kayıtları esas alınacaktır', 'www.vakifbank.com.tr I 0850 222 0 724', 'Türkiye Vakıflar Bankası T.A.O. Büyük Mükellefler V.D. 9220034970 Sicil Numarası: 776444','Saray Mahallesi Dr. Adnan Büyükdeniz Caddesi No :7 / A-B Ümraniye /İSTANBUL Mersis: 0922003497000017','Saray Mahallesi Dr. Adnan Büyükdeniz Caddesi No :7 / A-B Ümraniye /İSTANBUL Mersis: 0922003497000017          Sf 2 \\ 3   ']
d = list(filter(lambda w: w not in stopwords, c))

e = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('CÜZDANDAN HESABA TRANSFER ', 'CÜZDANDAN HESABA TRANSFER İŞLEMİ'), d))

# Align the list elements by 4 in the appropriate order according to the 4 columns of the df
z=[]
for  i in range(int(len(e)/4)):
      y=((e[i*4:i*4+4]))
      z.append(y)

df = pd.DataFrame( z,columns=['ISLEM TARIHI', 'ACIKLAMA','TUTAR', "BANKOMAT PARA"])

# creating csv file
is_file=os.path.isfile('C:/Users/Desktop/abstract/Alışveris_Özeti.csv')
if is_file==False:
    
    df.to_csv("Alışveris_Özeti.csv", index=False)
    print('CSV file has created...')
else:
    print("CSV file already exists.")
```